# How do I Fix SQL Query Returning Error on Big Query

Tags: sql

I am currently doing the google data analyst course and i am following the instructor but my query keep returning an error in the line 4 (count)

SELECT
usertype,
CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) as route
COUNT(*) as num_trips,
ROUND(avg(cast(tripduration as int64)/60,2) as duration
FROM
`bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
group by
start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
order by
num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10

Comment: You're missing a comma before `COUNT(*) as num_trips`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "select" statement is not written correctly – it needs to follow "select x, y, z, ..." – commas separating each thing. In the query you posted, you're missing a comma after "route", just before "COUNT(*)".

To fix it, change your query from this:

```
SELECT usertype, 
CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) as route 
COUNT(*) as num_trips,
...
```

to this – includes comma after "as route"

```
SELECT usertype, 
CONCAT(start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name) as route,
COUNT(*) as num_trips,
...
```